# Let $G=GL(2,GF(3))$ be the group of all matrices $ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

> Let $G=GL(2,GF(3))$ be the group of all matrices $
>         \begin{pmatrix}
>         a & b \\
>          c & d
>         \end{pmatrix}
> $ whose determinants are not zero. and whose entries $a,b,c,d$ are taken from the finite field $GF(3)=\{0,1,2\}$. and $H = \{\begin{pmatrix}
>         a & b \\
>          c & d
>         \end{pmatrix} \in G : ad - bc = 1\}$ What is $o(H)$?

First of all, I've computed $o(G) = 48$, The columns have to be linearly independent. so first column is $3\times 3 = 9$ options, and $(0,0)$ can't be too, so total $8$ options. Second column, same thing but we need to take into consideration that there could be a scalar multiplcation with the first column, so we need to substract two scalars $1,2$ and we stay with $6$ options. Total is $o(G) = 48$. I've computed this value so I can use lagrange later.

Now, I need to find the matrices that their determinant gives $1$. Is there a way to find them efficiently without counting one after one? I think there're 24 options in total, but I'm not sure how to prove it without counting one by one.

I thought about taking

$ad = 0 \rightarrow bc = 2$, total of $5\times 2 = 10$ options

$ad = 1, \rightarrow bc = 0$, total of $5\times 2 = 10$ options

$ad = 2 \rightarrow bc = 1$, total of $2\times 2 = 4$ options.

total of $10+10+4 = 24$ options.

Then $o(H) | o(G) = 24 | 48 = 2$, and lagrange works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method works.  Here's an efficient way, though:

**Hint:** Note that $H$ is a subgroup, and that the coset
$$
\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1} H
$$
consists of all elements whose determinant is $2$.

Comment: How do I continue?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS well, if you know that, then you know that the set $G$ is broken into two sets of equal size.  One of these sets is $H$, the other is its coset, and the coset has as many elements as does $H$.  Conclude that $o(G) = 2o(H)$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have a surjective homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb F_3)&\to\Bbb F_3^\times\\
M&\mapsto\det M
\end{align*}
which has kernel precisely $H = \operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb F_3) = \{M\in\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb F_3)\mid\det M = 1\}$. Thus,
$$
\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb F_3)/\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb F_3)\cong\Bbb F_3^\times,
$$
and hence $2 = \#\Bbb F_3^\times = \#(\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb F_3)/\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb F_3)) = \#\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb F_3)/\#\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb F_3)$.